# Trigonometric reverse substitution integral question.

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following integral.

$$ \int \frac{1}{(x^2-4x+13)^2}\ dx $$

My try :

$$ \int \frac{1}{(x^2-4x+13)^2}\ dx $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{[(x-2)^2+9]^2}\ dx $$
$$ (x-2)^2-9 = x^2-a^2\ ,\ a=3,\ x=3\sec\theta\ x^2-a^2=9\tan^2\theta\ dx=3\sec\theta \tan\theta\ d\theta $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{(9\tan^2\theta)^2}\ 3\sec\theta\ \tan\theta\ d\theta $$

And I couldn't continue.

Comment: Try letting $x-2=3\tan\theta$, so $dx=3\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$. (You seem to have changed +9 to -9 in the next-to-last step.)

Comment: You have used $\sec^2\theta+1=\tan^2\theta$, which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x^2-4x+3=(x-2)^2+3^2$ and then $\tan \theta=\frac{x-2}{3}\Rightarrow x=2+3\tan \theta$, and $dx=3\sec^\theta d\theta$; $\cos \theta = \frac{3}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+3^2}}$:
$$\int \frac{dx}{[(x-2)^2+3^2]^2}=\int \frac{3\sec^2\theta d\theta}{3^4 \sec^4\theta} =\frac{1}{3^3}\int \frac{d\theta}{\sec^2\theta}=\frac{1}{27}\int \cos^2\theta d\theta$$
$$= \frac{1}{27}\int \frac{1+\cos 2\theta}{2} d\theta=\frac{1}{54}\int d\theta+\frac{1}{54}\int \cos 2\theta=\frac{1}{54}\theta+\frac{1}{54}\frac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta+c=$$
$$... $$